# How to create an Explorer-like folder browser control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, explorer

Using C# and WinForms in VS2008, I want to create a file browser control that looks and acts like the left pane in Windows Explorer. To my astonishment, such a control does not ship with .NET by default.

Ideally, I would like its contents to be exactly the same as in Explorer. For example, on Windows 7, it should show the Favorites and Libraries pseudo-folders. Of course, I do not want to code specifically for each version of Windows if I can help it.

I have browsed around, and there are some examples of such controls, but they are all hand-rolled and therefore won't work 100% the same as the one in Explorer.

Is there any way I can simply reuse the Explorer control instead? Or, if not, to get access to a tree of the items that it would show?

Comment: I suspect the Explorer control just uses a tree control and populates it within the dialog code. I don't think it would be a specific control that displays the folders. I could be wrong.

Comment: Are you looking for `FolderBrowserDialog`? ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx

Comment: @shahkalpesh: No, essentially I'm looking for the control used *inside* that dialog.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Microsoft provides [a walkthrough for creating a Windows Explorer style interface in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171645.aspx).

There are also several examples on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com) and other sites. Immediate examples are [Explorer Tree](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ExplorerTree.aspx), [My Explorer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/my_explorer.aspx), [File Browser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/FileBrowser.aspx) and [Advanced File Explorer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/advancedfileexplorer.aspx) but there are others. [Explorer Tree](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ExplorerTree.aspx) seems to look the best from the brief glance I took.

I used the search term `windows explorer tree view C#` in Google to find these links.

Comment: Again, those are reinventing the wheel, and bound to get it wrong in various corner cases. But I'm accepting this because you provided the largest number of useful links.

Comment: @Thomas: It think re-inventing the wheel is the only option you have as Windows doesn't expose that control for use outside of Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not as easy as it seems to implement a control like that. Explorer works with shell items, not filesystem items (ex: the control panel, the printers folder, and so on). If you need to implement it i suggest to have a look at the Windows shell functions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776426(VS.85).aspx.

Comment: "It's not as easy as it seems to implement a control like that." I realize that. Which is exactly why I would prefer not to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Shell MegaPack](http://www.ssware.com/megapack.htm) control set. It provides Windows Explorer like folder/file browsing with most of the features and functionality like context menus, renaming, drag-drop, icons, overlay icons, thumbnails, etc

Comment: I had already run into that. If this weren't my first commercial application, I'd happily pay those $299, but as it stands, I can't afford that.