# Menu in Winforms resembling folder explorer menu

Tags: c#, winforms, menu, treeview, root

How to create a menu in winforms which totally resembles the menu which appears on Left Hand Frame in Windows Explorer when we Explore any folder. The menu contains tree nodes and root nodes which appear & disappear by clicking on the + & - symbols.

Comment: Not sure but check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416963/how-to-create-an-explorer-like-folder-browser-control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's not a menu, it's a tree view. You can use the WinForms tree view, but out of the box it won't look exactly like the Explorer tree view. You need to apply the Explorer window theme.

You need to P/Invoke to call [`SetWindowTheme`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759827.aspx) passing the window handle of the tree and use "explorer" as the theme.

Paste the following code into a new class in your project, compile, and use this custom control instead of the built-in `TreeView` control.

```
public class NativeTreeView : System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
{
    [DllImport("uxtheme.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private extern static int SetWindowTheme(
        IntPtr hWnd, 
        string pszSubAppName,
        string pszSubIdList
    );

    protected override void CreateHandle()
    {
        base.CreateHandle();
        SetWindowTheme(this.Handle, "explorer", null);
    }
}
```

Note that this trick also works exactly the same way for the `ListView` control.

Comment: sir, its giving the following error---:  'menu_resembling_windows_menu.newmenu.CreateHandle()': no suitable method found to override

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple 'root' nodes in a WinForms treeview:

```
treeView.Nodes.Add("Root 1");
treeView.Nodes.Add("Root 2");
```

Instead of text above, they could be full nodes w/ children.

Comment: how to make a child node of Root 1- like ChildRoot1

Comment: also, i want that when i click on "Root 2" node then a form opens. is this possible? please mention the code also sir.

Comment: TreeNode tn = new TreeNode("Root 1");
tn.Children.Add(new TreeNode("ChildRoot1");
treeView.Nodes.add(tn);
//etc, etc

Comment: sir, it gives an Error : System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode' does not contain a definition for 'Children'

Comment: err, make that:
tn.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("ChildRoot1"));

Comment: @Jonas: sir, this is also working , tn.Nodes.Add("ChildRoot1");    , but what's the difference in this and the one you have mentioned--tn.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("ChildRoot1"));

Comment: Different overloads of the .Add method...if you wanted multiple children with their own children, you'd add individual nodes, if you just want the text, you can do it that way.

Comment: @Jonas: So for childroot1 , how would i create its further child namely SubChildofChildRoot1

Comment: Same way:

TreeNode tn = new TreeNode("Node name");
TreeNode otherTn = new TreeNode("Another node");
TreeNode yetAnotherTn = new TreeNode("Yet another node");
//so on, so forth
otherTn.Nodes.Add(yetAnotherTn);
tn.Nodes.Add(otherTn);

(edit: Lord, how does that code mini-markdown thing work for comments?)