# How to have left side menu like vb.net toolbox in my vb.net application

Tags: vb.net

I am building a billing application for my shop in VB.Net. I want to add left Sidebar menu in my application. I have googled my query but did get the result.  I want to add menu look like and function like a toolbox. how can I built look like a menu like a toolbox.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Sample example [Sample vb.net toolbox image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3AsP.png)

Comment: That is a TreeView.  Google "treeview explorer style" to find hits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Menu in Winforms resembling folder explorer menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360525/menu-in-winforms-resembling-folder-explorer-menu)

Comment: You can just use a TreeView : [TreeView (Explorer style)](https://i.ibb.co/3yDxVJc/Tree-View1.jpg)

Comment: See also [How to create an Explorer-like folder browser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416963/how-to-create-an-explorer-like-folder-browser-control).