# How to navigate in Windows Explorer using alternative ways in Windows Forms in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm looking for alternatives to "FolderBrowserDialog" and "SaveFileDialog" or how I can edit these screens.

I need to create **exactly** the same interface of the image attached and the big challenge for me is how navigate/access the Windows Explorer like that in C#, as I didn't found how to edit the default save or select folder screens provided by C#.

[Create log screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5CGJ.png)

Comment: Hi Ivo. Did you try something? If you have some code then we may help to improve.

Comment: No "editing", these dialogs are baked into the operating system.  The screenshot shows what SaveFileDialog looked like 18 years ago.  You can still move that clock back by setting its AutoUpgradeEnabled property to False.  Intentionally making your app look dated is not usually a great idea.

Comment: Hello! I looked for ways to edit the interface and buttons of the default screens of FolderBrowserDialog and SaveFileDialog, but my first impression is these are a MS Windows default screen and not a screen provided/implemented by C#, so I probably will not be able to edit these screens. So I'm looking for another ways to access the folders, but everything I found until now to navigate within Win Explorer uses FolderBrowserDialog. By now, I don't know others ways to do this unless this two.

Comment: Hello Hans, I'm simulating a program (WinFIOL) for educational purposes, and this screen will create a file to continuously save what the user type in the command line interface. In a first step, this screen create a empty file in the location defined by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own file dialog using [TreeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/treeview-control-windows-forms)
Check Daniel's answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049822/really-custom-openfiledialog-net) post

Comment: Hello, Mehmet! I need something like this, really thanks, it will help me a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help.