# How do I get the destination folder in explorer

Tags: c#, explorer, file-move

I'm working on a program to "replace" the windows move file-dialog. For this new dialog to work in a similar manner I want to be able to

1. select one or more files
2. drag them to or right-click a destination folder
3. instead of choosing "Move here" I choose my program through an extra context menu that I add

I can without problem get all selected files from explorer, but how do I get the destination folder?

Comment: There seems to be a lot of overlap between your project and the following:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416963/how-to-create-an-explorer-like-folder-browser-control.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @bwyn, but not really. What I'm trying to do here is not build a new explorer clone from scratch but rather jack in to the shell when the move/copy is performed. Since I'm able to get the selected files without a problem it shouldn't be _too_ hard to get which folder the cursor is pointing on...