# how to get path to physical directory path of desktop in C#

Tags: c#

[image]

I tried

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
```

they both return same results

Comment: Those should work. What makes you think they don't?

Comment: I am trying to get desktop directories like in the above picture.

Comment: `var dd = Directory.GetDirectories( Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)  );`

Comment: And what do those methods you listed return, and how is that different to what you expect?

Comment: My Documents does not exist as a subdirectory of the Desktop folder on disk. If you want this tree specifically I think you'd need to get it from the Windows Shell API, but I don't know exactly how.

Comment: those methods don't return My Documents and others

Comment: Here's an MSDN article that calls this [the Shell Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/namespace-intro). There's no C# code there though.

Answer (score 0):

This image in the question representing a **Windows File Explorer** view of the **Desktop** root item is a **virtual view** constructed by the explorer.

As I know it has no physical existence on the drive and its content varies with the Windows version from 95 to 10.

The *Desktop folder* in the *User folder* on the drive only contains links and files shown on the screen (the desktop).

Perhaps there is a WinAPI to get such list but I don't know.
Perhaps it is somewhere in the registry.
Perhaps you can found something with Explorer-like implementations.

[How to create an Explorer-like folder browser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416963/how-to-create-an-explorer-like-folder-browser-control)

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/17e8f6/windows-explorer-in-C-Sharp-net/

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15059/C-File-Browser

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-info

Comment: I think your third link, the CodeProject C# File Browser, is the correct one, particularly [the Shell classes](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15059/C-File-Browser#TheShellclasses). It is for an old version of .NET, though, so might not just work out of the box.